# How to get back disappeared menu toolbar of Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, 64-bit, windows-explorer, toolbar

In Windows XP SP2 x64, Windows Explorer started to appear without menu toolbar.

How/why did this happen and how  can I get it back? 
I tried to search for shortcuts, tigh-clicking on panels, looking into pop-up tips of WE at another XP machine and search internet but still without any clue.

[image: Windows Explorer lost its menu toolbar]

Comment: See this....http://support.microsoft.com/kb/962963

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/962963)

Close all open Internet Explorer and Windows Explorer windows.

Open the Windows Registry Editor.

For Windows XP, Click Start, and then click Run , and then In the Open box, type: `regedit`  and then click OK.

Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar

**For Windows Explorer: In the details pane, locate the Explorer subkey, and then open it. In the details pane, locate the ITBarLayout value. Right-click this value, and then click Delete.**

On the File menu, click Exit to exit Registry Editor.

Did this fix the problem?

Check whether the problem is fixed. If the problem is fixed, you are finished with this article. If the problem is not fixed, you can try the following:

Close all open Internet Explorer and Windows Explorer windows.

Click Start, and then click Run.

In the Open box, type regedit, and then click OK.

Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar\ShellBrowser

In the details pane, locate the ITBarLayout value. Right-click this value, and then click Delete.

On the File menu, click Exit to exit Registry Editor.

Comment: Thanks. But I have the problem with Windows Explorer not Internet Explorer

Comment: Did you read the title of the article? "or in Windows Explorer on Windows XP" Check my edit in Bold type.

Comment: thanks, I shall check it when I am back on that remote machine